# How to turn off login pop-up on stackoverflow

Tags: authentication, popup, chromium, stack-overflow

When I am browsing stack overflow I keep getting a pop-up that asks me to login (only on stackoverflow). Is there a way to turn this off (besides removing the credentials and logging in)?

[popup chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfic6.png)

It also happens on Edge.

[popup edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zYhp.png)

I tried turning off my extensions (ublock origin and sponsorblock) and I tried changing site-settings to do not allow "Pop ups and redirects"

Comment: Questions about using [so] belong on [meta]

Comment: Yes, I'm having the same problem and it's extremely annoying! I don't want to login every time I just pop in to see an answer to a question. Stackoverflow, please remove this or tell us how to disable it. It never used to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
To fix it, go to Browser Settings > Passwords > search for stackoverflow and delete stored userid and password.
After removing the account, browser stopped showing these login popups.